# Can barely hear HTML5 audio through earphones

Tags: ios, html, cordova

I'm using the HTML5 audio implementation in my PhoneGap code. The implementation looks like this below:

```
myAudio = new Audio(path.mp3);
myAudio.play();
```

The problem is that the media is only audible when I'm listening through my devices speakers. Once I plug-in earphones, I can barely hear the sound coming out.

I tried using the volume attribute to raise the volume to the max.

```
myAudio.volume = 1.0;
```

But that didn't make a difference.

Then I checked the current volume by adding this line:

```
alert(myAudio.volume);
```

That returned `1`, meaning it's already at the max.
Any ideas?